# Installing apache 2.4 and php 5.5 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, package, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get, apache2.4

I'm trying to set a test enviroment with apache 2.4 and php 5.5 on a vm with ubuntu 12.04, fist thing is to add the repositories

```
apt-add-repository ppa:ptn107/apache
apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Then installing apache 2.4

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
```

checking apache version:

```
# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Sep 23 2013 07:23:34
```

Installing PHP 5.5

```
apt-get install php5-common php5-mysqlnd php5-xmlrpc php5-curl php5-gd php5-cli php5-fpm php-pear php5-dev php5-imap php5-mcrypt
```

Checking php version

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.8-3+sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jan 24 2014 10:15:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
     with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

So everyting seems ok the thing is I need mod_fastcgi but can't be installed:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you haverequested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-fastcgi : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So if mod_fastcgi can't be enabled how can I run php files with php-fpm ? Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: To extend a little, I didn't use `mod_fastcgi` in the end, instead I use `ProxyPassMatch` .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install the fastcgi mod and apache2 from here, verified that it works on my end. https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2?field.series_filter=precise

Comment: Yes using `ppa:ondrej/apache2` instead of `ppa:ptn107/apache` worked. I can see now how this is obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to suci and wedev's answer above, if you see an error like:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-   bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
```

because you did something dumb (like I did for example with an attempt to install php5 over top of php2.3 provided by the ubuntu image I'm working with), you can run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-data_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2_2.4.16-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1_amd64.deb
```

as outlined here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666720/ubuntu-apt-get-upgrade-error-on-ubuntu-12-04 by user3703155

which I believe instruct the package manager to stomp over any broken dependencies regarding the apache2 installation.

Subsequently running

```
apt-get install -f
```

followed by

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it was all happy after that.

```
php -version
PHP 5.5.30-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:14:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with XCache v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
with XCache Optimizer v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
with XCache Cacher v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
with XCache Coverager v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
```