# Ubuntu 12.04 PHP 5.5 and apache2 2.4

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, php-5.3

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, I decided to upgrade to PHP 5.5 from 5.3 and apache2 2.2 to 2.4. I did something similar to [Installing apache 2.4 and php 5.5 on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390544/installing-apache-2-4-and-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04). Long story short something's broken and it's not working correctly so I want to go back to PHP 5.3 and apache2 2.2.

Is it just a case of uninstalling PHP and Apache, removing the sources I added, do a package update and then reinstalling PHP and Apache using apt? I just want to go back to a version of PHP and Apache that work correctly and are supported by 12.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that matches the ppa names you added. You should find one like `ondrej`

Run then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5 apache2` and you should have all back working

I've used ondrej ppa too (There are apache 2.4 and mysql 5.6 too from the same author which works really well for me, https://launchpad.net/~ondrej)